# sigill on glBindFramebuffer

Tags: linux, opengl

The program crashes at glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb); in the function gen_texture

gdb tells me "Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction."

```
void gen_texture(GLuint &color, int width, int height)
{
   GLuint fb;

   glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
   glGenTextures(1, &color);

   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
...



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   glutInit (&argc, argv);
   glutInitContextVersion(4, 3);
   glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

   std::cout << std::hex << glGetError() << "\n" << std::flush;

   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
   glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);
   glutCreateWindow ("");
   glutDisplayFunc (display);
   glutIdleFunc (display);

   std::cout << std::hex << glGetError() << "\n" << std::flush;


   glewExperimental=GL_TRUE;
   GLenum err=glewInit();
   if(err!=GLEW_OK)
   {
      std::cerr << "glewInit fehlgeschlagen, aborting." << std::endl;
   }

   gen_texture(texture, 100, 60);
...
```

Comment: I don't see a question here, just several statements. Are you asking why your program is crashing? If so, is `glGenFramebuffers()` returning a valid value? Does `glGetError()` report any issues before calling `glBindFramebuffer()`?

Answer (score 1):

In this code

```
GLenum err=glewInit();
if(err!=GLEW_OK)
{
      std::cerr << "glewInit fehlgeschlagen, aborting." << std::endl;
}
```

just because GLEW returns OK for initialization this doesn't mean all extensions are loaded. Also checking `glGetError` will not report you GLUT errors (like that the context you requested is not supported. In `glGetError` only reports OpenGL errors (GLUT is not a part of OpenGL) and in addition must be called in a loop until it returns `GL_NO_ERROR`.

I suggest you add a bit more detailed error diagnostics and report back.

Comment: @user2798943: Did you change anything on your error reporting? Also did you add that glGetError fetching loop? Anyway, that you get an error at all may indicate, that you don't get the kind of context you asked for. make sure you have a OpenGL implementation (i.e. GPU + matching drivers) that support what you ask for; you ask for OpenGL-4.3 core profile, which ATM is supported by only NVidia hardware no older than 2 years with the latest drivers, downloaded directly from the NVidia website.

Comment: I've added the glGetError fetching loop, and I'm using a gtx 660m with the latest nvidia driver.

Comment: I've changed the code to a OpenGL-3.1 core profile, the GL_INVALID_ENUM​ disappeard but it still crashes at the glBindFramebuffer function.

Comment: @user2798943: There is no such thing as a 3.1 core profile :) This problem is created by `GL_EXTENSIONS` being an invalid enumerant for `glGetString (...)` in OpenGL 3.2 core. There is a new function to query individual extensions instead of the massive list of strings, but GLEW does not use this behavior unless you set `glewExperimental = true;` before calling `glewInit (...)`. It has to do this because the function required in OpenGL 3.2 core is, itself, loaded using the extension mechanism... a chicken and egg situation that is only resolved by manually telling GLEW that you have 3.2 core.

Comment: @user2798943: The concept of core profiles was introduced with version 3.2, for future reference.

Comment: okay, now I've changed it to 3.2 and I've got the GL_INVALID_ENUM​ error back.

Comment: glewExperimental​ is a variable that is already defined by GLEW. You must set it to GL_TRUE before calling glewInit()​.
We can ignore the GL_INVALID_ENUM error.

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library says:

"You might still get GL_INVALID_ENUM (depending on the version of GLEW you use), but at least GLEW ignores glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)​ and gets all function pointers."

Comment: The sigill error only appears when I linked the program to the efence memory debugger.